# current user filter web part in SharePoint

Tags: web-part, filter

I would like the user to only see their tasks that are meant to their department
for example (IT Users when they are logged into to Tasks list ) they should only see Tasks for IT department only.

I am trying to use Current User Filter Web Part but when I select edit web part and then go to "SharePoint profile value for Current user" drop-down list is empty.

Please see attached photo and help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting as you have logged in with user who is also system account. Please login with normal site collection admin(who is not configured as system account in central admin) and it should work.